# Why is my minecraft server overwriting weather commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

So, we've tried all these commands, doweathercycle, weather, toggledownfall, but, our server just writes a new command on it's own to set it back to thunder and lightning. We're looking for a permanent fix, is it a mod, or a plugin? We are running the Tekxit 3 LE modpack.

Comment: Can you post your full server details, plugin (if applicable) and mod list?

Answer (score -1):

I think you maybe used the command

`/gamerule doWeatherCycle`

what only SHOWS the current state of the current server settings for this gamerule

to disable the weather you must run the command:

`/gamerule doWeatherCycle false`

and if you like to re-enable it run

`/gamerule doWeatherCycle true`